# How to retrieve data from a SharePoint List by using REST URL?

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint, odata

First, please assuming that my company domain name is `www.aaa.com`, and I am trying to retrieve a list data from the SharePoint list REST endpoint. The list that I am trying to access is used in the following webpage:

```
http://www.aaa.com/tpn/toolcenter/esri/Pages/Portal/Portal.aspx
```

And I can get the list names with:

```
http://www.aaa.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/
```

and I think the list name that I am looking for is called "Pages".

Then I am trying to compose the Odata REST url to get the list data from browser but failed. The url that I tried is:

```
http://www.aaa.com/sites/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Pages')
```

The error message that I get is a `http 404`. Could anyone please let me know what might be wrong for my OData url?

Appreciate your help very much!

Comment: You may want to visit http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com.  Specifically https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135936

Comment: Thanks, Spevy. I have posted my question on the SharePoint StackExchange site.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you're starting "_api".

Assuming that "esri" is a site, try the following:

```
http://www.aaa.com/tpn/toolcenter/esri/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Pages')
```

This url seems off too but I'm basing it on your sample.  Basically, you start from the site where your list or library is stored, then append _api and everything else.